# Car does not start first time

Tags: starting, vw, jetta

This is a 1.6 Mk4 Jetta that was losing power.I sent it in for fixing. After it came back the power problem is fixed but the car won't start first time as before the engine overhaul. It starts on the third time now.Someone suggested i look into the timing also check if it does not lose pressure on the petrol pump

Comment: Is this a diesel Jetta or petrol/gasoline?

Comment: it is a 1.6 petrol engine with automatic transmision